# Populate list of list using displaytag

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I am using struts2 and display tag to show results in a grid format. All the information present in the list is populated. However when I need to populate data from the Arraylist present inside original list, I fail to populate and gives error Unknown property.

For example:

```
<display:table id="txt" name="resourceList"  requestURI="" pagesize="10" cellpadding="50px;" cellspacing="100px;" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:50px;" export="true">
    <display:column property="resource_Code" title="Code"></display:column>
    <display:column property="resource_Fname" title="First Name"></display:column>
     <display:column property="resource_LName" title="Last Name"></display:column>
    <display:column property="resource_RJILEmpCode" title="RJIL Emp Code"></display:column>
    <display:column property="customerPO" title="PartnerPO End Date"></display:column>

</display:table>
```

When I want to print list"customerPO" inside the "resourceList" I get error as unknown property "code". Here code is an attribute present inside the "customerPO" and this customerPO is a list.Please advice me how to print the nested list using display tag

```
<display:table id="txt" name="resourceList"  requestURI="" pagesize="10" cellpadding="50px;" cellspacing="100px;" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:50px;" export="true">
    <display:column property="resource_Code" title="Code"></display:column>
    <display:column property="resource_Fname" title="First Name"></display:column>
     <display:column property="resource_LName" title="Last Name"></display:column>
    <display:column property="resource_RJILEmpCode" title="RJIL Emp Code"></display:column>

    <display:column property="customerPO.code" title="PartnerPO code"></display:column>
<display:column property="customerPO.name" title="PartnerPO Name"></display:column>

</display:table>
```

Comment: The list couldn't be a column of displaytag, post the code.

Comment: Actually I am trying to populate the attributes inside this "customerPO" i.e customerPO.code,customerPO.startDate etc. So the code should be like this:<display:column property="customerPO.code" title="PartnerPO Code"></display:column>.......I hvae updated the code

Comment: So, `customerPO` is not a list, what is the list then?